# Converting PHP web service from JAX-RPC to JAX-WS

Tags: php, web-services, jax-ws, jax-rpc

Is there any way to convert JAX-RPC to JAX-WS web service. The issue is we need to generate a client of this PHP based web service in java. The web service is written in PHP in RPC style, and when java team try to generate the client it get error "Selected wsdl is rpc encoded. You must select JAX-RPC Client" so we are requested to change the encoding style from RPC to WS can any one help in this regard

**EDIT**
[Here is a plugin for netbeans](http://www.stormacq.com/netbeans-7-0-and-jax-rpc-web-service/) that allow user to generate java based jax-rcp client. but as pre client requirement we need to change the web service. That is why need that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't you generate a JAX-RPC client? This is not ideal but if your *server* is RPC style, why do you want a JAX-WS client?

Comment: @ZNK-M java team say that jax-rpc is deprecated or going to be deprecated that is why.

Comment: i found a plugin that allow Netbeans to generate the jax-rpc based client using java, but that is an other option, this time i want to convert from jax-rpc to jax-ws